# How to create CSV from Python byte objects

Tags: python, csv, binary, byte, codec

I have a type of binary file that must be converted into a CSV. The output CSV must have 10 columns describing

- Date (4 bytes) - 8 digit int
- Time (2 bytes) - short int
- Open (2 bytes) - short int
- High (2 bytes) - short int
- Low (2 bytes) - short int
- Close (2 bytes) - short int
- Tick Count (2 bytes) - unsigned short int
- Volume (2 bytes) - long int
- Average Bid Size (4 bytes) - float
- Average AskSize (4 bytes) - float

A sample records from the binary file looks like

`b'CCFM\x01\x00\x02\x00\x12:-\x01\r\x07\xd65\xd65\xd65\xd65\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12:-\x01\x12\x07\xd65\xd65\xd65\xd65\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12:-\x01\x05\x00\xd65\xd65\xd65\xd65\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12:-\x01\n'`

The binary file has the header "`CCFM\x01\x00\x02\x00` and I must add 28 bytes for every column. How would I write a Python function that converts the binary file to a csv file?

Comment: Check out the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module. You can unpack the data into a tuple and then use `csv.writer` to write rows to a file.